# killing Parent process along with child process using SIGKILL

Tags: linux, shell, unix, pid, kill-process

I am writing one shell script in which I have parent process and it has child processes which are created by `sleep &` command. Now I wish to kill the parent process so that the child process will be also killed. I was able to do that this with below command:

```
trap "kill $$" SIGINT
trap 'kill -HUP 0' EXIT
trap 'kill $(jobs -p)' EXIT
```

These commands are working with `kill [parent_process_ID]` commands but if I use `kill -9 [parent_process_ID]` then only the parent process will be killed.
Please guide me further to achieve this functionality so that when I kill parent process with any command then child process should be also killed.

Answer (score 11):

When you kill a process alone, it will not kill the children.

You have to send the signal to the process group if you want all processes for a given group to receive the signal.

```
kill -9 -parentpid
```

Otherwise, orphans will be linked to `init`.

Child can ask kernel to deliver `SIGHUP` (or other signal) when parent dies by specifying option `PR_SET_PDEATHSIG` in `prctl()` syscall like this:

```
prctl(PR_SET_PDEATHSIG, SIGHUP);
```

See `man 2 prctl` for details.

Comment: I have tried but I think I do not have function called  prctl

Answer (score 5):

Sending the `-9` signal (`SIGKILL`) to a program gives *no chance* for it to execute its own signal handlers (e.g., your `trap` statements). That is why the children don't get killed automatically. (In general, `-9` gives *no* chance for the app to clean up after itself.) You have to use a weaker signal to kill it (such as `SIGTERM`.)

See [`man 7 signal`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man7/signal.7.html) for details.