# Kill all the processes started by the script invoked from shell script

Tags: python, linux, shell, unix

I have a shell script which in turn starts a python script. Python script further creates a process pool and does its stuff.

```
conda activate app_env
... some other shell commands ...

clean() {
   # make sure all process created by python and python itself
   # gets killed
}

trap clean SIGINT

python start_server.py
```

When someone manually tries to exit the script using `ctrl+c`, I need to make sure that all the processes started by python get killed. Is there a way where I could all the child process started by the shell script in one go or may be step by step?

Right now, I listen for the `ctrl+c` signal and then execute the cleaning function. After I have detected the `ctrl+c` signal, how do I kill the processes started by `python` i.e started by this shell script

Comment: Do you want to kill the processes from the shell script or Python?

Comment: @AlexW shell script

Answer (score 0):

If killing the python script would kill the processes you could use a trick with GNU screen. Start the python process as:

```
screen -S session_name -d -m your_python_process
```

and kill it in clean() with:

```
screen -X -S session_name quit
```

If this is not an option because killing the main python script would not kill all processes then maybe you should have a look at this SO question: [How to kill zombie process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16944886/how-to-kill-zombie-process) or this one: [killing Parent process along with child process using SIGKILL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869242/killing-parent-process-along-with-child-process-using-sigkill)