# how to kill uwsgi process without worker respawn

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

I have had trouble to kill uwsgi processes.
Whenever I use below commands to shutdown uwsgi, another uwsgi workers respawned after a few seconds. So after shutdown uwsgi process and start up uwsgi server again, uwsgi processes continues to accumulate in memory.

- sudo pkill -f uwsgi -9
- kill -9 `cat /tmp/MyProject.pid`
- uwsgi --stop /tmp/MyProject.pid

I want to know how to kill uwsgi processes not making uwsgi workers respawned.
I attach ini file as below.

```
[uwsgi]
chdir            = /home/data/MyProject/
module           = MyProject.wsgi
home             = /home/data/anaconda3/envs/env1
master           = true
pidfile          = /tmp/MyProject.pid
single-interpreter = true
die-on-term     = true 
processes       = 4
socket          = /home/data/MyProject/MyProject.sock
chmod-socket    = 666
vacuum          = true
```

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

at first:

1. `uwsgi` is a [binary protocol that uWSGI uses to communicate with other servers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UWSGI). `uWSGI` is an application server.
2. You should avoid ([1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184071/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-9-option-in-the-kill-command), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869242/killing-parent-process-along-with-child-process-using-sigkill)) to use `-9` (`SIGKILL`) to stop process if you care about child processes (workers)

what I can say according your information:

> Whenever I use below commands to shutdown uwsgi, another uwsgi workers
> respawned after a few seconds

Looks like you trying to kill worker (child) process but not uWSGI application server (master process). Here is `processes = 4` in your config, so application server (master process) watching for minimum running workers (child processes). And if one of it exited (by `KILL` signal or source code exception, no matter) application server starting new 4th process.

> So after shutdown uwsgi process and start up uwsgi server again

If `uwsgi process` is a worker (child process) - see answer above

If `uwsgi process` is an application server (master process) - here is another problem. You using `KILL` (`-9`) signal to stop server. And that is not allow to exit application properly (see `at first`'s second point). So when your application server is unexpectedly killed, it leave all 4 child processes running without parent (master) process (say hello to [orphaned process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688982/zombie-process-vs-orphan-process))

You should to use `SIGTERM` instdead of `SIGKILL`. Do you understand meaning of [`die-on-term = true`](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Upstart.html#what-is-die-on-term)? Yeah! That means `please stop stack of all processes on SIGTERM`.

> uwsgi --stop /tmp/MyProject.pid

This command [should stop](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Management.html#signals-for-controlling-uwsgi) all processes properly. Here is no information in your question to decide what problem that may be...

I have three guesses:

1. web application source problem: exit operation is not handled properly
2. `die-on-term = true` [inverts the meanings of SIGTERM and SIGQUIT to uWSGI](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Upstart.html#what-is-die-on-term), so maybe `stop` working like `reload` in this case? not sure.
3. some kind of misunderstanding

#### Update 1: how to control number of child processes dynamically

In addition, you may check this [helpful article](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Cheaper.html) to understand how to scale-in and scale-out child process dynamically to be able run all 4th processes only when it needed and run only 1 process when service is idle.

#### Update 2: CHeck if behaviour reproducible

I created simple uWSGI application to check behaviour:

```
opt
`-- wsgi_example
    |-- app.py
    `-- wsgi.ini
```

- wsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
chdir            = /opt/wsgi_example
module           = app
master           = true
pidfile          = /opt/wsgi_example/app.pid
single-interpreter = true
die-on-term     = true
processes       = 2
socket          = /opt/wsgi_example/app.sock
chmod-socket    = 666
vacuum          = true
```

- app.py

```
def application(env, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
    return [b"Hello World"]
```

I running this application by `wsgi wsgi.ini`
I stopping this application by `uwsgi --stop app.pid`

Output is

```
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 15797)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 15798, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 15799, cores: 1)
SIGINT/SIGQUIT received...killing workers...
worker 1 buried after 1 seconds
worker 2 buried after 1 seconds
goodbye to uWSGI.
VACUUM: pidfile removed.
VACUUM: unix socket /opt/wsgi_example/app.sock removed.
```

All working properly. All processes stopped.
Your question is not reproducible.

Search for the  problem inside application code or your individual infrastructure configuration.

※ checked with `uWSGI 2.0.8` and `2.0.19.1` and `python 3.6.7`

Comment: First, I really appreciate your answer!! As you mentioned regarding "die-on-term=true", when I stop application by using "uwsgi --stop /tmp/MyProject.pid" command, the child process killed and new child process respawn right away. I share uwsgi log as below

Comment: `SIGINT/SIGQUIT received...killing workers...
worker 1 buried after 1 seconds
worker 2 buried after 1 seconds
worker 3 buried after 1 seconds
worker 4 buried after 1 seconds
goodbye to uWSGI. pp)
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 18825)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 18830, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 18831, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 18832, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 18833, cores: 1)`

Comment: I want to block workers(another child processes) from being respawned after previous child processes killed

Comment: @JoJay 1. what is result of using `SIGTERM` (`kill -15 $PID`) instead of `SIGKILL`? 2. what is result of using `uwsgi --stop /tmp/MyProject.pid` if you set `die-on-term=false`?

Comment: 2. what is result of using uwsgi --stop /tmp/MyProject.pid if you set die-on-term=false? -> result is same with die-on-term=true. The child processes was killed and new child processes respawn right away

Comment: @JoJay I updated my answer. I can't reproduce your problem so can't help more over